# Confused by flag feedback

Tags: discussion, flagging, declined-flags

I recently flagged some posts as 'very low quality' because I thought they were examples of "bad subjective" and didn't answer the question.

They were declined, and the reason was:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I'm confused by this response, since I didn't think there were technical inaccuracies or that they were altogether wrong.

Can anyone should more light on this?  Just trying to understand the feedback better.

Comment: For the record, I don't mind that they were declined.  I just don't get the feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be clear, the questions were on various answers to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/167305/4).

I declined the flags because it was an inappropriate use of the flags.

Answers can not be "bad subjective" - that criteria only applies to questions. The definition of a low quality answer is something that doesn't provide a reason or explanation, only consists of a link, it's commenting on the question or another answer, and so on. The flagged answers were well written and explained themselves, and I disagreed that they didn't answer the question - they did provide real world examples of the use of dynamic typing.

The only other reason to delete an answer is if it's abusive in some way, such as advertising with no disclosure, unrelated spamming, or is offensive or abusive toward members of the community.

In this case, the problem was not the answers, but the question. The question received 5 close votes for not constructive. It also received a large number of answers, which is something that could indicate a non-constructive question or a question that is too broad, since it could indicate that there's no right answer if people aren't norming on a few best ideas for the condition.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense than the flag feedback.